# Typescript - get prop. from partial object

Tags: typescript

### Issue

The issue is obvious. But why the `i()` (invariant) function doesn't do its job? It has to remove `undefined` from `Database | undefined` because if is `this.#storage[name]` `undefined`, the function `i()` will throw an error. Or no?

Is possible to solve this issue without `as` in typescript?

### Error

```
Type 'Partial<Storage>[Name]' is not assignable to type 'Storage[Name]'.
  Type 'Database | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Database'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Database'.

(2322)
```

### Code

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwCNIFNoG8C+BYAUAQPRHQC0FlV1ZBBAZgK4B2wCAlgPbPTsAUwbgBN2HbgC5oYZgE8ANNAC2aKGADmaSRAQAndszUBKSZAhodCGIOYixPTAWi960PgEJrtrs0NZHT6AQACx1OAHdoZjQIgFEdUJ0+ZVUNQwBufzx8LOJSGnzKOnxQU2gAYW4ENAAPBD98JwBibU4ddU1oAAUwC3YwEAAeCuYq2oA6AGUEVvaAPmgAXixsDMIGqSh2NWYpmY0BgDkwZWgaqpsYAGs0GU4XYdGESem2jVm+ZmOOo+UFFteOg8zs89mgANo-NAAXWMgSC7BgDnWTmCCLGzRe7TBn2UUMW0H+7VW-icOjQCEYOh4qIgqycOXWhP2kNOtTQF2g11u90qwN2APeOO+X1hQPG-KxkLxSICvD4NPRTPBQqhCgA5GUAPIHAAqMQAGjqAPoTHWagBKAEEAOIxI0HTXGy0TCYASWtBxisDV6SKsrJFKpcLRGNB2K+ULS0BI0EAvBuALx3oG5kzqAJqdGITMrm12dHXQGLm80W5NuOPxzIEBlCiAABzAwAwYrqMtZtdadX0VR09AbGAlGnqsqEiBQ6Ek8CQqDMdOgWQZNXbFmgQjQvcYIDqzbSQA)

```
class Database {}

// ----------------

function i(condition: any, message: string): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(message);
  }
}

// ----------------

class Context {
  #storage: Partial<Context.Storage> = {};

  assignStorage<Name extends keyof Context.Storage>(name: Name, storage: Context.Storage[Name]): this {
    this.#storage[name] = storage;

    return this;
  }

  storage<Name extends keyof Context.Storage>(name: Name): Context.Storage[Name] {
    i(this.#storage[name], 'CONTEXT_STORAGE_NOT_ASSIGNED');

    return this.#storage[name]; //  !!!TYPESCRIPT ERROR!!! 
  }
}

namespace Context {
  export interface Storage {
    database: Database;
  }
}

export default Context;
```

Comment: pls share reproducable example

Comment: The _fun_ thing is that if I copy your code on VS Code and test it, it works ...

Comment: @mwryl which typescript version do you use?

Comment: @Altaula same as the playground, v.4.3.4.

Comment: @mwryl playground throws an error so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- add `as Context.Storage[Name]` at the return
- make all the fields of your interface optional, and avoid using `Partial` and force ignore the undefined value

**The issue**

Your `i()` function is working well, and is not the issue.

The issue is the `Partial` which basically has a return type of `Context.Storage[Name] | undefined` for each property, which does not match with `Context.Storage[Name]` because the `undefined` is missing some properties (obviously).

So your assertion is here to validate that the property you're checking is indeed defined. However this is not enough for Typescript, because it wants to be sure that the value is of the type you want to return, and because of the `Partial` part, being sure that it is defined is not a guarantee that it is of the same type of the property of the class.

**The unwanted solution**

I don't think there is a possibility to validate the type of the value on runtime. But you can bypass this issue with the `as Context.Storage[Name]` because your assertion is saying that if it is defined, then it has to be this type (even though you asked for a different way, but I don't think there is one related to this specific issue).

```js
class Database {}

// ----------------

function i(condition: any, message: string): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(message);
  }
}

// ----------------

class Context {
  #storage: Partial<Context.Storage> = {};

  assignStorage<Name extends keyof Context.Storage>(name: Name, storage: Context.Storage[Name]): this {
    this.#storage[name] = storage;

    return this;
  }

  storage<Name extends keyof Context.Storage>(name: Name): Context.Storage[Name] {
    i(this.#storage[name], 'CONTEXT_STORAGE_NOT_ASSIGNED');
    return this.#storage[name] as Context.Storage[Name];
  }
}

namespace Context {
  export interface Storage {
    database: Database;
  }
}

export default Context;
```

To confirm that Typescript is right on this issue, try this code:

```
let brokenStorage: Partial<Context.Storage> = {
  database: 2 // value is not a Database
}
```

Here we have a broken storage that contain a number as a `Database`. It can be initialized without a problem and this is what Typescript is warning of. Because if another person came after you and adds a method that fill wrong values into your `storage` field, Typescript cannot block them, because the `Partial` type does allow such behavior.

But it can warn you of the fact that you may not have the type that you are asking for in your field.

**The alternative solution**

The alternative could be to make all the properties of the interface optional. With this you would avoid using the `Partial` and go directly with your interface:

```js
class Database { }

// ----------------

function i(condition: any, message: string): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(message);
  }
}

// ----------------

class Context {
  #storage: Context.Storage = {};

  assignStorage<Name extends keyof Context.Storage>(name: Name, storage: Context.Storage[Name]): this {
    this.#storage[name] = storage;

    return this;
  }

  storage<Name extends keyof Context.Storage>(name: Name): Context.Storage[Name] {
    i(this.#storage[name], 'CONTEXT_STORAGE_NOT_ASSIGNED');

    return this.#storage[name]!;
  }
}

namespace Context {
  export interface Storage {
    database?: Database;
  }
}

export default Context;
```

You can see that we added `!` at the return to ignore the undefined values. Because your assertion is already checking that the value is defined.

However, for both solutions, you can break the storage by putting a random value.

Assuming that we have this method in the Context class:

```
breakStorage() {
  this.#storage = {
    database: 2
  };
}
```

This works in both "solutions". Because the first one, we have a `Partial` storage, while the second one we have an `interface` that have an optional field (so if the field has a different type, then it is still compliant with the interface because it was optional anyway).

Comment: alternative solution does not work because `context.storage('database')` will throw error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts (2532)`

Comment: You can add `!` at the end to ignore the undefined value, like this: `let database = context.storage("database")!;`

Comment: Okay I am stupid, this is actually the solution. You can ignore the undefined value by adding `!`. I updated my answer so that you just change this on your original code.

Comment: if you add random property to class Database... your solution with `!` does not work... so only solution with `as` operator is VALID

Comment: Yes you are right. I will re update my answer. :3

Comment: Here you go, I think both solutions are good now. The alternative works because the `!` will resolve the `undefined` error. And both still has the possibility to get broken with a malicious function that has access to the storage. And let's not forget that since it is `javascript`, the second someone starts playing with your class outside of `typescript` he can assign whatever he wants. ^^'